# Changing the property of outer DIV while hovering over inner <a> Element

Tags: css, button

I am trying to make a button in a purely CSS way (I am trying to avoid javascript as much as possible)
I have the following code

CSS:

```
.Button a{
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:transparent;
Height:100%;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
.Button a:hover{
background-color:brown;
cursor:default;
}
.Button a:active{
background-color:gray;
}
```

Now, my problem is that I wish to change the background color of the outer element (the one with class as 'Button'). The above code changes the background color of the  element rather the the enclosing . Any ideas how I can get this (without using javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question, in the hope that the others, who might stumble upon this thread later on, can benefit if they have the same problem (so that they need to crawl the web as much as I did today :-P).

As, Elusive said, it is **NOT** possible to select a parent element through CSS-selectors.

And the code below worked for me:

```
a.Button {
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:transparent;
display:block;
Height:100%;
min-width:100px;
color:white;
padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
text-decoration:none;
}
a.Button:hover{
background-color:brown;
cursor:default;
}
a.Button:active{
background-color:gray;
}
```

I made the < a> element display style 'block'. And I was able to achieve the effect I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo class `:hover` can be applied to non anchor elements as well:

```
div.Button:hover {border:1px solid red}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that IE (6 i think) has problems with `:hover` being applied to non-`<a>`-elements.

Comment: The problem with `:hover` on the parent is that when you change the color of something you're hovering over, it's a visual cue telling the user that they can interact with it.  If someone's in the div, but not in the link, then the div will highlight but clicking won't do anything -- and the user's left wondering what's wrong.

Comment: @goreSplatter: Yes, but, in that case, how can I use the 'active' pseudo class for the element (like: div.Button:active {...} )

Comment: @cHao as that may well be true, it's the designer's resposibility to have the `<div>` do something. after all, he's the one who wanted it to visually react to hovering... there's no point in it not reacting to clicking then, as well.

Comment: @Thrustmaster That's difficult. Is it possible for you to have the `<a>` element be the parent? Then you could do `a:active span {...}`. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible...

Comment: @goreSplatter: Thing is, if i'm understanding right, he wants the div to react when the *link* is hovered over.  That's perfectly fine, but i don't know of a way to do it with just CSS and HTML.

Comment: @cHao: Exactly! May be I should have phrased it better.

Comment: @goreSplatter: I tried that before, But I wasnt able to set the height properly. The 'display:block;' did the trick. Thanks once again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. CSS-selectors are not capable of selecting parent elements. They cannot walk up the DOM. That is why i prefer XPath over CSS-selectors.

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit unsure about this before. :-)