# Changing properties of one div element when hovering above other div elements

Tags: css, html, hover

Sorry to bring this up again since I am quite sure it was answered in threads like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353398/changing-the-property-of-outer-div-while-hovering-over-inner-a-element), yet posting in older threads appears to be pointless.  But I'd like to know whether  this is still true that I will in fact need jQuery (or something similar) in order to change the properties of one div-element when hovering above some other div-element?

If the answer would still be yes, please have a look at the following picture: 
[image]

This is part of my navigation I am trying to bring to life right now. As you can see there is some kind of mirror effect underneath the buttons. I want those buttons to be clickable while having a "hover" background-position / background-image change. I tried to do that with a single div-element which didn't work out since the button-area itself is smaller than the entire graphic so even when I was hovering above the reflection the button was ready to be used which was not very intuitive.

Currently I am using a div-element to display the background image including the hover effect and - sorry but I don't really know how to describe the following - some kind of "invisible" text link which is forced to a specific size in order to simulate a clickable area. Here a small visualization: 
[image]

Green is the area of the background image which is changing upon hovering above the div-element and the red area is the "button".

So again the question ... do I still need something like jQuery to get this hover effect working only when I hover above the button area, are there different approaches to this or ... is something like jQuery really the only answer to that?

Comment: with pure CSS (2.1) you can only make selectors deeper into the DOM tree. So a hover over a parent can change a child element, but not the other way around. So no hover over a child can change it's parent. With jQuery other possibilities open up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a quick solution that is working in Firefox 3.6, you can [try it at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWxH3/3/).

It is not exactly the answer to your question, but offers a solution to your design.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="target1.html" id="button1">
        <div id="reflection1-active"></div>    
    </a>
    <div id="reflection1-inactive"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position: relative;   
}
#button1{
    background-color: #900;
    height: 32px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;   
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#button1:hover{
    background-color: #F00;
}
#button1 #reflection1-active{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f77;   
    height: 32px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
    top: 32px;
    display: none;
}
#button1:hover #reflection1-active{
    display: block;
}
#button1 #reflection1-active:hover{
    display: none;   
}
#reflection1-inactive{
    background-color: #977;
    height: 32px;
    width: 80px;
    top: 32px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am at work right now but it looks just like what I was searching for, I'll play around with that later on, thanks so far!

Comment: Considering my goals I had to go with the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637611/property-changing-of-child-div-elements-image-flickering - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

when you hover on an element (link/button) inside another element (parent div) you are actually still hovering on the parent element too so you can effect the two of them at the same time:

HTML:
`<div><a href="#">the button</a></div>`

CSS:

```
div {width: 100px; height: 200px; background: green;}
a {display: block; height: 100px; background: #000;}

div:hover {background: #cfc;}
a:hover {background: #eee;}
```

If I'm understanding the question right, the background (green to lightgreen) changes no matter if you're on the "button area" or not (`div:hover`), whereas the button area only changes when you're on the button itself as it's effected by only the `a:hover`

[Update]

actually I think I have misunderstood the question: you want to change the background image of the div only when you hover the `<a>` (button)?

put the new full background on the `<a>` and have it change it's height too it will mean a bigger "button" area, but that will only be when the button is actually hovered on anyway

try this CSS instead:

```
div {width: 100px; height: 200px; background: green;}
a {display: block; height: 100px; background: #eee;}

a:hover {background: #000; height: 200px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether any browsers support this, and I've never tried, but...  Could you use a selector for a sibling adjacent to the hovered element, and then use the adjacent element to render the shadow?  Since the adjacent element is not a child of the hoverable element, hovering over that would not trigger the hover selection match.